# can global variables be accessed by two threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, queue

Im trying to implement queue in c programming with eclipse IDE, i have two threads where first one is producer and second is consumer which will process data and log file

i will be using enqueue function from producer thread

```
void enqueue(int *q,int *tail, int element){ q[(*tail)++] = element;}
```

and Dequeue function from consumer thread

```
int dequeue(int *q,int *head){return q[(*head)++];}
```

[image]

So is it possible for me to use enqueue and dequeue simultaneously?
will it cause any issues on my code?

Comment: Based on the queue is a critical section so you should be careful about the access of threads  to shared resource .

Comment: What happens if the consumer thread calls dequeue but the producer thread hasn't enqueued yet?

Comment: As for your question in the title: "Yes". A thread is just an execution path through your code. Multiple threads mean multiple paths executing at the same time, through the same code, and so can access the same data.

Comment: you need to make sure that only one thread may modify the resuorce. For example by using the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

> can global variables be accessed by two threads?

Of course yes, since the several [threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) of the same [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) share a common [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

### Details are of course [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) specific.

I am supposing you have some Linux OS.

You probably should use locking or synchronization facilities. With [POSIX threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/), look into `pthread_mutex_init`, `pthread_mutex_lock`,  and related functions like `pthread_condvar_init`

You want to read the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

You want to read the documentation of your [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), e.g. the documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or of [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/). You probably should also read about your [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)), e.g. documentation of GNU [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).

You want to read the documentation of your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, e.g. of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/).

You need to read the documentation of your debugger, perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).